# SELECT exibindo produtos exceto os resultados de um outro SELECT

Tags: php, sql, query

Tenho esse `SELECT` que pega os 6 produtos mais vendidos:

```
SELECT IdProduto, SUM(QtdProdutoPedido) as QtdProdutoPedido FROM tb_pedidoproduto 
GROUP BY IdProduto ORDER BY QtdProdutoPedido DESC LIMIT 6
```

Queria um `SELECT` que mostrasse todos os outros produtos cadastrados exceto os mostrados com o `SELECT` acima.
Tentei usar `NOT EXIST`:

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_produto` WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT IdProduto, SUM(QtdProdutoPedido) as QtdProdutoPedido FROM tb_pedidoproduto 
     GROUP BY IdProduto ORDER BY QtdProdutoPedido DESC LIMIT 6) 
&& IdCategoria = 2 ORDER BY IdProduto ASC
```

Mas não consegui monta-lo.
Se tiver um modo de fazer em PHP pode ser também.

---

Tentei usar o NOT EXISTS mas está trazendo os resultados que não existe na tabela tb_pedidoproduto, creio que o LIMIT não está funcionando:

```
SELECT produto.IdProduto, produto.NomeProduto, produto.IdCategoria, produto.Imagem, 
produto.QtdMedida, produto.ValorProduto, produto.IdUnidadeMedida, produto.DescricaoProduto 
FROM tb_produto as produto WHERE produto.IdCategoria = '2' AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT pedidoproduto.IdProduto, SUM(pedidoproduto.QtdProdutoPedido) as QtdProdutoPedido 
FROM tb_pedidoproduto as pedidoproduto
WHERE produto.IdCategoria = '2' 
AND produto.IdProduto = pedidoproduto.IdProduto 
GROUP BY pedidoproduto.IdProduto ORDER BY QtdProdutoPedido DESC LIMIT 6) 
ORDER BY produto.IdProduto ASC
```

Basicamente o que preciso é subtrair os resultados do primeiro SELECT com os do segundo, tentei fazer um SELECT usando o operando "-" mas não funfou também. Alguém me ajuda plss . . .

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tb_produto WHERE IdProduto NOT in (SELECT IdProduto, SUM(QtdProdutoPedido) as QtdProdutoPedido FROM tb_pedidoproduto GROUP BY IdProduto ORDER BY QtdProdutoPedido DESC LIMIT 6) && IdCategoria = 2 ORDER BY IdProduto ASC`

Comment: " #1235 - Esta versão de MySQL não suporta ainda 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' " , deu zinaba man :^/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query

Answer (score 3):

Você pode pegar todos os resultados, EXCETO OS 6 PRIMEIROS mais vendidos, usando `LIMIT` com dois parâmetros:

```
LIMIT 6,18446744073709551615
```

Isso irá retornar na query a partir do 7º registro até o último.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo **[Documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#id4651990)**:

> *To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last.*
>
> `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;`
>
> **Tradução:** para recuperar todos os registros a partir de um certo ponto
>   até o fim do resultado, você pode usar um número grande no segundo
>   parâmetro [...]

Para ordenar o resultado pelo `IdProduto`, inclua `, IdProduto` após `QtdProdutoPedido DESC`:

```
SELECT IdProduto, SUM(QtdProdutoPedido) as QtdProdutoPedido FROM tb_pedidoproduto 
GROUP BY IdProduto ORDER BY
QtdProdutoPedido DESC, IdProduto
LIMIT 6,18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento. Não tinha noção dessa alternativa válida.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação na versão 5.7(atual) do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-errors.html). Há alguns erros que se aplicam somente as `subqueries`. O erro descrito por você nos comentário é um deles.

- Sintax não suportadas nas `subquery`:

  ERROR 1235 (ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET)
  SQLSTATE = 42000
  Message = "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support
  'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Um script utilizado como exemplo na documentação é semelhante ao seu:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE s1 IN (SELECT s2 FROM t2 ORDER BY s1 LIMIT 1)
```

Nestes casos utilize um atributo de comparação entre as tarefas. Porcure usar o atributo que faz relação entre as duas tabelas para otimizar a consulta.

Sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_produto AS produto
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM tb_pedidoproduto AS pedidoProduto
        WHERE
            pedidoProduto.IdCategoria = 2
                AND pedidoProduto.primaryKeyDaTabela IS NOT NULL
                AND pedidoProduto.IdProduto = produto.IdProduto
        GROUP BY pedidoProduto.IdProduto
        ORDER BY COUNT(pedidoProduto.QtdProdutoPedido) DESC
        LIMIT 5
    );
```

Obs.: Adicionei a linha `AND pedidoProduto.primaryKeyDaTabela IS NOT NULL` por causa `primaryKeyDaTabela` pode ser null e retornara `false`. Como consequência o `count()` irá contabilizar todos os 'falsos' juntos. Isso será uma informação errada para o script superiror tomar a decisão que qual produto irá trazer. Por este motivo a solução foi add `NOT NULL` para os retornos da `primaryKeyDaTabela`.

Você pode fazer um teste e executar o `SELECT` dentro o `NOT EXISTS ()` separado. Assim poderá comprovar se algum `IdProduto` retornará como `null`

Qualquer dúvida ou erro comenta ai